# Why my test is failing here?

Tags: solidity, testing, unittesting, foundry, forge

I am writing a test for checking a upgradable contract:

```
function test_Proxy() public {
        vm.startPrank(address(user));   // checking is non-owner address can call the upgradeTo() or not
        vm.expectRevert();
        proxy.upgradeTo(address(_game));
        game.generateMonster{value: 0.01 ether}();   // CALLING A FUNCTION TO BEFORE UPGRADE, SO THAT IT SET THE addressToMonsterId = 1
        assertEq(game.addressToMonsterId(address(user)), 1);   //ASSERTING THAT addressToMonsterId = 1.
        vm.stopPrank();
        vm.startPrank(address(me));
        proxy.initialize(address(_game)); // Initializing the proxy contract
        address _addr =proxy.getImplementedAddress();
        console.log("implemented address is", _addr);
        proxy.upgradeTo(address(_game));   // UPGRADED THE CONTRACT WITH NEW IMPLEMENTATION
        assertEq(_game.addressToMonsterId(address(user)), 1);  /// THIS ASSERTION SHOULD BE PASSED   
}
```

But the problem is this test i failing by:

```
Error: a == b not satisfied [uint]
        Left: 0
       Right: 1
```

Why? As far as i know upgraded contract should persist the before upgrade's state, and if it persists then `assertEq(_game.addressToMonsterId(address(user)), 1)` should not fail. What is happeing?

My proxy contract looks like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract Proxy is Initializable, UUPSUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    address implemented;

    function initialize(address _newImplementation) public initializer {
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
        __Ownable_init();
        implemented = _newImplementation;
    }

    function upgradeTo(
        address newImplementation
    ) external virtual override onlyOwner {
        _authorizeUpgrade(newImplementation);
        _upgradeToAndCallUUPS(newImplementation, new bytes(0), false);
    }

    function _authorizeUpgrade(
        address newImplementation
    ) internal virtual override {}

    function getImplementedAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return implemented;
    }
}

// https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x3ca6ef0bda6b10ae9bef670e4ef655ff583383f4
```

Answer (score 0):

some questions:

1. When calling generateMonster you have to call the proxy:

   `proxy.generateMonster{value: 0.01 ether}();`

   Doing `game.geneate..()` assuming that `game` is the address of the implementation will actually store the state into your implementation and, therefore, not persist in the proxy contract
2. In `the testProxy()`, it can not be seen that you have already deployed the proxy, deployed the implementation, and initialized the proxy with the first implementation. In the case that this happened in the `setUp()`, you don't require to re-initialize the Proxy contract. The Proxy contract will only initialized once, and the `upgradeTo` when a new implementation

Hope it helps!

Comment: here is what i have done : => 1. In `setUp()` i created `game` instance, `_game` instance  which is implementation address and `proxy` instance by deploying. Did not initialize any contract here i.e did not called initialize() => Now in `test_proxy` => called the `upgradeTo()` of **proxy** contract where it will be reverted because we did not initialize, it is intentional => initialized the **game** contract [ not implementation] => called the `generateMonster()` of **game** => SO NOW WE HAVE monsterId = 1 (before upgrade) => initializing **proxy** contract with *_game* (implementation) =>

Comment: the game instance, is using the proxy address or the implementation?

Comment: called `upgradeTo()` with implemented address => Now initializing the _game contract as it is redeployed ( **Despite of it is redeployed should i initialize it again?) => checking the the `monsterId`'s value is persisting or not

Comment: game instance is not using proxy instance , nor it is the implementation, it is just first condition of contract, before upgrading

Comment: How it will work `proxy.generateMonster{value: 0.01 ether}();`?

Comment: Actually, you have to interact with the proxy instance, the game implementation should not be instantiated, only passed to the proxy contract

Comment: As far as i understood proxy contract is just used to change the implementation address, thats all, What else it does? 
Do u use telegram?? Because here i can't provide u the code or my explanation properly due to space.

Comment: I will prefer not to disclose my TG in a public page. however the proxy contract holds the state and use delegateCall to the implementation logic contract, so all interactions you want to have with your contract should use the Proxy contract. Try it and you will see the test is working.

Comment: **so all interactions you want to have with your contract should use the Proxy contract.** - How i can use proxy contract here? I mean the function i am using is in the **_game** contract, by `_game.<function_name()>`so how the proxy can be used here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145717/discussion-between-donoso-eth-and-hacek).